# underscore each and extend

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

hi guys i'm struggle to understand how can i solve something.

i have 7 dates , that i have to add for each date six different value of time slot number , the results need to look this.

```js
{
"dateTime": "2017-05-25T09:20:58.846Z",
    "timeSlotArray": 
      {
        "available": true,
        "placeAfter": "string",
        "placeBefore": "string",
        "slotNumber": 0
      }
}

{
"dateTime": "2017-05-25T09:20:58.846Z",
    "timeSlotArray": 
      {
        "available": true,
        "placeAfter": "string",
        "placeBefore": "string",
        "slotNumber": 1
      }
}
{
"dateTime": "2017-05-25T09:20:58.846Z",
    "timeSlotArray": 
      {
        "available": true,
        "placeAfter": "string",
        "placeBefore": "string",
        "slotNumber": 2
      }
}

{
"dateTime": "2017-05-25T09:20:58.846Z",
    "timeSlotArray": 
      {
        "available": true,
        "placeAfter": "string",
        "placeBefore": "string",
        "slotNumber": 3
      }
}

{
"dateTime": "2017-05-25T09:20:58.846Z",
    "timeSlotArray": 
      {
        "available": true,
        "placeAfter": "string",
        "placeBefore": "string",
        "slotNumber": 4
      }
}

{
"dateTime": "2017-05-25T09:20:58.846Z",
    "timeSlotArray": 
      {
        "available": true,
        "placeAfter": "string",
        "placeBefore": "string",
        "slotNumber": 5
      }
}
```

but i'm failing to add each numbers to slotNumber

```js
var startDate = new Date()
var endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

var date = new Array()

for (var iDate = new Date(); iDate < endDate; iDate.setDate(iDate.getDate() + 1)) {
  date.push(iDate)
}

var numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

addDateData = function(x) {
  return {
    date: x,
    timeSlot: {}
  }
}

addTimeSlot = function(x) {
  _.each(numbers, function(y) {
    _.extend(x.timeSlot, {
      available: true,
      placeAfter: "",
      placeBefore: "",
      slotNumber: y
    })
  })
}

var data = _.chain(date)
  .map(addDateData)
  .each(addTimeSlot)
  .value()
  
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

anyone can help me to understand what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: The expected result is unclear for me... Should the result be an array of "days" where each "day" has an array of timeslots: `[{day:"2017-05-25", timeslots:[0,1,2,...]}, {day:"2017-05-26", timeslots:[0,1,2,...]}]`? Or an array of (days * timeslots) "days" where each day has one timeslot: `[{day:"2017-05-25", timeslots:[0]}, {day:"2017-05-25", timeslots:[1]}, {day:"2017-05-26", timeslots:[0]}, {day:"2017-05-26", timeslots:[1]}]`?

Comment: hi andreas thank you for taking time to answer to my question.
i updated the desired output in my question, this results is the one date , should be the same for all the seven dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not that "satisfied" with the expected result, but I will give it a shot.

This will add the days consecutively in the same array without any separation.

```
[
  { day: 1, timeSlot: 0 },
  { day: 1, timeSlot: 1 },
  { day: 2, timeSlot: 0 },
  { day: 2, timeSlot: 1 },
  //...
]
```

```js
var startDate = new Date(),
    endDate = new Date(startDate.getTime() + 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000),
    numbers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    date = [];

for (var iDate = new Date(); iDate < endDate; iDate.setDate(iDate.getDate() + 1)) {
  numbers.forEach(function(n) {
    date.push({
      date: new Date(iDate),
      timeSlot: {
        available: true,
        placeAfter: "string",
        placeBefore: "string",
        slotNumber: n
      }
    });
  });
}

console.log(date);
```

Comment: thank you for your shoot andreas, but it appear that you are looping throw the same date https://jsfiddle.net/xxeorLjf/

Comment: @PrinceZee Argh... Wrong version... I've updated the code :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you simplify your `addTimeSlot` function, you will get the result you are looking for.

```js
addTimeSlot = function(x, index) {
  _.extend(x.timeSlot, {
    available: true,
    placeAfter: "",
    placeBefore: "",
    slotNumber: index
  })
}
```

If I understand correctly, it looks like your `slotNumber` attributes are just index numbers. Since you are using the `addTimeSlot` function inside of an `each` method, you could just use the index numbers themselves.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/yffvw126/